# Special case of Kolmogorov forward equation of generator matrix

Tags: probability, graph-theory, numerical-methods, markov-chains

Let $Q$ be a stable conservative generator matrix of a discrete state space Markov process over time interval $[0,T]$
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Discretizaion of the Kolmogorov forward equation $\frac{\partial P(t)}{\partial t}=P(t)Q(t)$ allows one to approximate the initial value problem of $P(0)=I$ using $0=t_{0}<t_{1}<...<t_{N}=T$ for small enough $\epsilon=T/N$ as follows
$$
P(t_{n+1})=P(t_{n})(I+Q\epsilon)
$$
such that the first $3$ steps are given by
$$
P(t_{0})=I\qquad P(t_{1})=I+Q\epsilon\qquad P(t_{2})=(I+Q\epsilon)^{2}
$$
I want to approximate $P(t)$; however, it is now given that everytime a Markov chain makes the transition $1\rightarrow2$, the value of $Q_{1,2}$ increases with $\delta>0$ (and subsequently $Q_{1,1}$ decreases with $\delta$, such that $Q$ remains stable conservative). (This discretization scheme neglects the possibility of multiple transitions in a time interval of $\epsilon$ as it can be shown that this probability converges to $0$ faster than the probability of a single transition.)

A difference from the classical problem is that $Q$ is essentially not memoryless and stochastic.

I was wondering if it is possible to approximate $P(t)$ using discretization and if not, why not? (and if so, how?)

I have made several attempts, which are too elaborate to include, therefore I was wondering if there is anyone who is familiar with any useful literature or comparable algorithms?

Comment: Well, you can restore stochastic and memoryless by working in the state space $\{1,2\}\times\mathbb{N}$, keeping track of the the number of transitions $1\to 2$, no?

Comment: Discretizing over time interval $T$ with small enough $\epsilon$ to justify linear approximation of exponentially distributed holding times would demand too much memory as you need to keep track of every $1\rightarrow2$ transition for every possible path from $1$ to (eventually) $2$ with the number of possible paths from $1$ to $2$ increasing with $2^{n-1}$. This is a computational problem, so essentially I want to write $P(t_{n})$ in the form of $(I+Q(t_{0})\epsilon)(I+Q(t_{1})\epsilon)\dots(I+Q(t_{n})\epsilon)$ or $(I+Q\epsilon)^{n}+\xi(t_{n})$, such that memory does not run out.

Comment: No, we are not tracking the $2^{n-1}$ possible paths, but employing a cut-off on the number of transitions and compute with the resulting $2N$-state Markov chain.  Memory shouldn't run out if the interval time $T$ is not huge.  The expected time to make $N$ transitions $1\to 2$ and back is approximately $2N+\delta^{-1}\log N$, so a rough estimate like Chebyshev's bound gives $2N\leq T+O(\sqrt{T})$ states to consider, and now compute with $\epsilon\leq \frac1{c+\delta T}$ that justify linear approximation in this cut-off version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expanded version of what I wrote in the comments, with some numerical trials.

Note that the dynamics is precisely a hidden Markov model where the underlying Markov chain occurs on $\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N}$ where the $\mathbb{N}$ factor is tracking the number of transitions $1\to 2$.  Of course this gives us an infinite state space, which computationally is going to be very expensive.  Hence we seek to approximate this.

For the sake of argument, let's say we choose a tolerance level of $\epsilon_{tol}$.  If probability of more than two jumps in an interval is below $\epsilon_{tol}$ we will just ignore that and use the linear approximation.  So for sanity, we will also cutoff the number of transitions $1\to 2$ that we track to about this level, meaning we model the chain on state space as $\{1,2\}\times\{0,1,\dots,N-1\}$ with generator $Q$ such that
\begin{align*}
Q_{(1,k),(2,k+1)} &=\frac12+k\delta,\quad 0\leq k< N-1\\
Q_{(2,k),(1,k)} &=\frac12,\quad 0\leq k\leq N-1
\end{align*}
whether we allow $(1,N-1)$ to move to $(2,N-1)$ won't matter with our tolerance level, so let's say we don't allow escape from $(1,N-1)$.

How can we get hold of this parameter $N$?  We know the distribution of the holding times is a [hypoexponential distributed variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution) with $N$ of the $\lambda_i=\frac12$ and $N$ $\lambda_i$ being an arithmetic progression $\frac12,\frac12+\delta,\dots,\frac12+(N-1)\delta$, but that is pretty much stating the obvious.  Fortunately, if the $\lambda_i$ doesn't vary too much, we can appeal to [Welch-Satterthwaite equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation) approximating a sum of independent Gamma-distributed variables as another Gamma by matching the first two moments:
$$
\sum X_i\sim\operatorname{Gamma}\left(\alpha=\frac{(\sum\alpha_i/\beta_i)^2}{\sum\alpha_i/\beta_i^2},\beta=\frac{\sum\alpha_i/\beta_i}{\sum\alpha_i/\beta_i^2}\right),\quad 
$$
In particular, since we have $X_i\sim\operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda_i)=\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha=1,\beta=\lambda_i)$, this simplifies to
$$
\sum X_i\sim\operatorname{Gamma}\left(\alpha=\frac{(\sum\lambda_i^{-1})^2}{\sum\lambda_i^{-2}},\beta=\frac{\sum\lambda_i^{-1}}{\sum\lambda_i^{-2}}\right)
$$
and hopefully you should have (regularised) lower incomplete gamma function $P(\alpha,x)$ in your software library so you can just perform a few steps of a root-finding algorithm for $N$ in
$$
P\left(\frac{\left(2N+\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac1{\frac12+k\delta}\right)^2}{4N+\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac1{(\frac12+k\delta)^2}},\frac{2N+\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac1{\frac12+k\delta}}{4N+\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac1{(\frac12+k\delta)^2}} T\right)\lessapprox\epsilon_{tol}
$$
This $N$ is roughly between $\frac12T$ and $T$ for small $\delta$ and small to medium $T$, as one would expect.  We run the system starting at $(1,0)$ or $(2,0)$ and extract the observed states $1,2$ at time $T$

---

**Experimental results:** If $\delta=0.1$, $T=100$, $\epsilon_{tol}=10^{-6}$, the Gamma approximation gives $N=72$.  I also run a reference using $\epsilon_{tol}=10^{-14}$ and $N=2000$ (which takes about 2 minutes on this old computer, using mostly Python except for squaring the matrices which is delegated to faster numpy implementations).

For the reference $P_{11}=0.102791$, $P_{22}=0.895243$.
The value of observed $P_{11}$ and $P_{22}$ are:

| $N$ | $\log_2(T/\Delta T)$ | $P_{11}$ | $P_{22}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 2 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 3 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 4 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 5 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 6 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 7 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 8 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 9 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 10 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 11 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 12 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 13 | 16 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 14 | 17 | 1.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 15 | 17 | 1.000000 | 0.000001 |
| 16 | 17 | 0.999999 | 0.000003 |
| 17 | 17 | 0.999997 | 0.000009 |
| 18 | 17 | 0.999990 | 0.000023 |
| 19 | 17 | 0.999973 | 0.000058 |
| 20 | 17 | 0.999934 | 0.000138 |
| 21 | 17 | 0.999845 | 0.000309 |
| 22 | 17 | 0.999656 | 0.000652 |
| 23 | 17 | 0.999281 | 0.001306 |
| 24 | 17 | 0.998571 | 0.002490 |
| 25 | 17 | 0.997296 | 0.004528 |
| 26 | 17 | 0.995119 | 0.007874 |
| 27 | 17 | 0.991568 | 0.013125 |
| 28 | 17 | 0.986030 | 0.021014 |
| 29 | 17 | 0.977759 | 0.032383 |
| 30 | 17 | 0.965905 | 0.048126 |
| 31 | 17 | 0.949576 | 0.069099 |
| 32 | 17 | 0.927926 | 0.096022 |
| 33 | 17 | 0.900260 | 0.129367 |
| 34 | 17 | 0.866143 | 0.169258 |
| 35 | 17 | 0.825491 | 0.215411 |
| 36 | 17 | 0.778639 | 0.267102 |
| 37 | 17 | 0.726353 | 0.323206 |
| 38 | 17 | 0.669798 | 0.382270 |
| 39 | 17 | 0.610452 | 0.442637 |
| 40 | 17 | 0.549985 | 0.502585 |
| 41 | 17 | 0.490113 | 0.560476 |
| 42 | 17 | 0.432459 | 0.614877 |
| 43 | 17 | 0.378424 | 0.664662 |
| 44 | 17 | 0.329101 | 0.709059 |
| 45 | 17 | 0.285223 | 0.747667 |
| 46 | 17 | 0.247155 | 0.780425 |
| 47 | 17 | 0.214928 | 0.807560 |
| 48 | 17 | 0.188290 | 0.829516 |
| 49 | 17 | 0.166781 | 0.846879 |
| 50 | 17 | 0.149805 | 0.860305 |
| 51 | 17 | 0.136702 | 0.870462 |
| 52 | 17 | 0.126808 | 0.877983 |
| 53 | 17 | 0.119495 | 0.883436 |
| 54 | 17 | 0.114202 | 0.887309 |
| 55 | 17 | 0.110448 | 0.890005 |
| 56 | 17 | 0.107840 | 0.891845 |
| 57 | 17 | 0.106062 | 0.893076 |
| 58 | 17 | 0.104874 | 0.893885 |
| 59 | 17 | 0.104095 | 0.894406 |
| 60 | 17 | 0.103594 | 0.894736 |
| 61 | 17 | 0.103277 | 0.894941 |
| 62 | 17 | 0.103080 | 0.895066 |
| 63 | 17 | 0.102960 | 0.895141 |
| 64 | 17 | 0.102888 | 0.895186 |
| 65 | 18 | 0.102846 | 0.895211 |
| 66 | 18 | 0.102822 | 0.895226 |
| 67 | 18 | 0.102808 | 0.895234 |
| 68 | 18 | 0.102800 | 0.895238 |
| 69 | 18 | 0.102796 | 0.895241 |
| 70 | 18 | 0.102793 | **0.895242** |
| 71 | 18 | **0.102792** | 0.895243 |
| 72 | 18 | 0.102791 | 0.895243 |
| 73 | 18 | 0.102791 | 0.895243 |
| 74 | 18 | 0.102791 | 0.895244 |
| 75 | 18 | 0.102791 | 0.895244 |
| 76 | 18 | 0.102791 | 0.895244 |
| 77 | 18 | 0.102791 | 0.895244 |
| 78 | 18 | 0.102791 | 0.895244 |
| 79 | 18 | 0.102791 | 0.895244 |
| 80 | 18 | 0.102791 | 0.895244 |

If we let $(1,N-1)$ jump back to $(2,N-1)$, then we get a slightly faster convergence.

| $N$ | $\log_2(T/\Delta T)$ | $P_{11}$ | $P_{22}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 0.500000 | 0.500000 |
| 2 | 16 | 0.454545 | 0.545455 |
| 3 | 16 | 0.416667 | 0.583333 |
| 4 | 16 | 0.384615 | 0.615385 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 59 | 17 | 0.102794 | **0.895242** |
| 60 | 17 | **0.102792** | 0.895243 |
| 61 | 17 | 0.102791 | 0.895243 |
| 62 | 17 | 0.102791 | 0.895244 |
| 63 | 17 | 0.102791 | 0.895244 |
| 64 | 17 | 0.102791 | 0.895244 |

---

We could also do some adaptive stuff and increment $N$ as needed.  In other words, starting with $3$ states, at each stage $(1,N-1)$ sends to a coffin $\partial$, and when this coffin state accumulates $>\epsilon_{tol}$ we rename it $(2,N)$, create two states $(1,N)$ and $\partial$, and continue with new time step size $\Delta T$.  This probably has worse time performance though as we are not leveraging the fast squaring and the amount of copying that is needed when we increment $N$, but if you want to track the observed $P_{ij}$ over time then this may be a better algorithm.

---

**Addendum**: With adaptive $N$ and step-size, it takes approximately 5 minutes with 400k+ steps to compute the case $T=100$, $\delta=0.1$ and $\epsilon_{tol}=10^{-6}$, with the final $N=72$.  This compares with the rather naive implementation of predetermined $N=72$ taking approximately 20 minutes with all $2^{18}=262144$ steps filled in.  I'll post a cleaned-up version of my code later.

---

**Addendum (2021-10-08)**: The python code

````
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math
import numpy
import scipy
import scipy.special
from scipy.optimize import newton, ridder


def hypo2cdf(lambda1, lambda2, x):
    """
        cumulative density function for Hypo(lambda1,lambda2)
    """
    x = float(x)
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if abs(lambda1 - lambda2) < 1e-14:
        return scipy.special.gammainc(2, (lambda1 + lambda2) * x / 2)
    return (lambda2 * numpy.expm1(-lambda1*x)
            - lambda1 * numpy.expm1(-lambda2*x))/(lambda1-lambda2)


def hypo2pdf(lambda1, lambda2, x):
    """
        probability density function for Hypo(lambda1,lambda2)
    """
    x = float(x)
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if abs(lambda1-lambda2) < 1e-14:
        return (lambda1+lambda2)/2 * x * math.exp(-(lambda1+lambda2)*x/2)
    return (numpy.expm1(-x * lambda2) - numpy.expm1(-x * lambda1))/(
        1/lambda2 - 1/lambda1)


def gamma_approx_prob(T, N=1, delta=0.1):
    """
        Returns the Gamma approximation to a sum of Gammas by first two moments
    """
    if isinstance(N, int):
        lambdas = [(0.5 + j*delta) for j in range(N)]
        thetas = [1/x for x in lambdas]
        theta2s = [x*x for x in thetas]
        first = sum(thetas) + 2 * N
        second = sum(theta2s) + 4 * N
    elif isinstance(N, float):
        # presumably during root-finding
        first = 2*N + (scipy.special.polygamma(0, N+0.5/delta)
                       - scipy.special.polygamma(0, 0.5/delta))/delta
        second = 4*N + (scipy.special.polygamma(1, 0.5/delta)
                        - scipy.special.polygamma(1, N+0.5/delta))/delta**2
    else:
        raise TypeError
    # scipy.special.gammainc is regularised lower incomplete gamma
    #   P(a,x)=\frac1{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^x t^{a-1}\exp(-t) dt
    alpha = first**2/second
    beta = first/second
    return scipy.special.gammainc(alpha, beta * T)


def rootfind1D(f, tol=1e-6, args=(), guess=None, bracket=None, fprime=None):
    """
        Find root with either Newton-Rhapson (when guess, fprime are provided)
        or Ridder (when bracket of root is provided)
    """
    if (guess is not None) and (fprime is not None):
        retval = newton(f, fprime=fprime, args=args, x0=guess)
        return retval
    elif bracket is not None:
        retval = ridder(f, args=args, a=bracket[0], b=bracket[1])
        return retval
    else:
        raise ValueError
    raise RuntimeError


def findN(T=100, delta=0.1, tol=1e-6):
    """compute "optimal" N for each T"""
    N = int(rootfind1D(lambda x: gamma_approx_prob(T, x, delta) -
            tol, tol=tol, bracket=[T/2, -math.log(tol)*T]))
    # check if we need to increment N
    while gamma_approx_prob(T, N, delta) > tol:
        N += 1
    return N


class chain:
    def __init__(self,
                 delta=0.1, N=None, T=100.0, tol=1e-6, options='adaptive_N'):
        """
        options is a space-separated list from:
            - one of 'adaptive_N' 'final_T' 'trajectory'
            - possible 'coffin' for coffin state for 'final_T' or 'trajectory'
            - possible 'coarse' to only consider P(>=2jumps) constraint on
              step-size deltaT , not ||Q deltaT||^2 estimate of remainder
              exp(Q deltaT) - I - Q deltaT.
            - also 'expQ' to compute with 'exp(Q deltaT)' instead of linear
              I+Q deltaT approximation
        """
        self._delta = delta
        self._tol = tol
        self._T = T
        self._opt = set(options.split(' '))
        if 'adaptive_N' in self._opt:
            self._opt.add('coffin')
            self._N = 1
            self.compute = self._compute_adaptive
        elif 'final_T' in self._opt:
            if N is None:
                N = findN(T, delta, tol)
            self._N = N
            self.compute = self._compute_end
        elif 'trajectory' in self._opt:
            if N is None:
                N = findN(T, delta, tol)
            self._N = N
            self.compute = self._compute_all
        else:
            self._opt = 'trajectory'
            if N is None:
                N = findN(T, delta, tol)
            self._N = N
            self.compute = self._compute_all
            pass
        self.resetQ()
        self._observed = [(0.0, numpy.eye(2)), ]
        self._currentT = 0.0
        self._currentP = numpy.eye(2*self._N + 1)
        pass

    @property
    def delta(self):
        return self._delta

    @property
    def tol(self):
        return self._tol

    @property
    def T(self):
        return self._T

    @T.setter
    def T(self, val):
        self._T = float(val)
        if self._T < 0:
            self._T = 0
        if self._currentT < self._T:
            self._currentT = 0
            self._observed = [(0.0, numpy.eye(2))]

    @property
    def N(self):
        return self._N

    @N.setter
    def N(self, val):
        oldN = self._N
        self._N = int(val)
        if self._N < oldN:
            self._N = oldN
            raise ValueError('Cannot decrease N')
        if self._N > oldN:
            self.resetQ()
            P = self._currentP
            self._currentP = numpy.eye(2*self._N+1)
            self._currentP[:P.shape[0], :P.shape[1]] = P

    @property
    def Q(self):
        return self._Q

    @property
    def observed(self):
        return self._observed

    def resetQ(self):
        self._Q = numpy.zeros((self.N*2+1, self.N*2+1))
        for i in range(self.N):
            self._Q[self._arrayidx(2, i), self._arrayidx(1, i)] = 0.5
            self._Q[self._arrayidx(2, i), self._arrayidx(2, i)] = -0.5
            self._Q[self._arrayidx(1, i), self._arrayidx(
                1, i)] = -0.5-i*self.delta
            if (i+1 < self.N):
                self._Q[self._arrayidx(1, i), self._arrayidx(
                    2, i+1)] = 0.5+i*self.delta
            elif 'coffin' in self._opt:
                self._Q[self._arrayidx(1, i), self._arrayidx(
                    state=3)] = 0.5+i*self.delta
            else:
                self._Q[self._arrayidx(1, i), self._arrayidx(
                    2, i)] = 0.5+i*self.delta

    def _arrayidx(self, state=1, count=0):
        # this version is better for expanding the matrix
        if state in [1, 2] and count < self.N:
            return count*2+(2-state)
        elif state == 3 and 'coffin' in self._opt:
            # coffin state
            return 2*self.N
        raise ValueError

    def stepsize1(self):
        """time step such that probability ( geq 2 jumps) < tol"""
        lambda1 = 0.5
        lambda2 = 0.5+(self.N-1)*self.delta
        gamma = scipy.special.gammaincinv(2, self.tol)
        if lambda1 == lambda2:
            return gamma/lambda1
        # since in cumulative probability sense
        # Exponential(lambda_1) > Exponential(lambda_2)
        # we have over and under estimates
        lower = gamma/lambda2
        upper = gamma/lambda1
        # geometric mean looks like a good place to start
        guess = gamma/math.sqrt(lambda1 * lambda2)
        return rootfind1D(
            lambda x: hypo2cdf(lambda1, lambda2, x) - self.tol,
            guess=guess,
            bracket=[lower, upper],
            tol=self.tol,
            fprime=lambda x: hypo2pdf(lambda1, lambda2, x))

    def stepsize2(self):
        """ |(Qh)^2| < tol """
        lambdamax = 0.5 + (self.N - 1) * self.delta
        return math.sqrt(self.tol/(self.Q.shape[0])) / lambdamax

    def determine_step_size(self):
        """ P(>= 2 jumps)<tol, and |(Qh)^2|<tol if coarse"""
        h1 = self.stepsize1()
        if 'coarse' in self._opt:
            return h1
        h2 = self.stepsize2()
        return min(h1, h2)

    def expQ(self, h):
        lambdamax = 0.5 + (self.N - 1) * self.delta
        if lambdamax*h > math.sqrt(self.tol/self.N/2):
            sqrt = self.expQ(h/2)
            return sqrt @ sqrt
        Qh = self._Q * h
        Qh2 = Qh @ Qh
        Qh3 = Qh2 @ Qh
        return Qh3 / 6 + Qh2 / 2 + Qh + numpy.eye(self.Q.shape[0])

    def _compute_end(self):
        h = self.T
        n = 1
        stepsize_det = self.determine_step_size()
        while h > stepsize_det:
            h /= 2
            n *= 2
        if 'expQ' in self._opt:
            IplusQh = self.expQ(h)
        else:
            IplusQh = numpy.eye(self._Q.shape[0]) + self._Q * h
            pass
        self._currentP = numpy.linalg.matrix_power(IplusQh, n)
        self._currentT = self.T
        obs = numpy.zeros((2, 2))
        for i in (1, 2):
            for j in (1, 2):
                obs[i-1, j-1] = numpy.sum(self._currentP[
                    self._arrayidx(i, 0),
                    [self._arrayidx(j, count) for count in range(self.N)]])
        self._observed.append((self._currentT, obs,))
        return obs

    def _compute_all(self):
        h = self.T
        n = 1
        logn = 0
        stepsize_det = self.determine_step_size()
        while h > stepsize_det:
            h /= 2
            n *= 2
            logn += 1
            pass
        if 'expQ' in self._opt:
            IplusQh = self.expQ(h)
        else:
            IplusQh = numpy.eye(self._Q.shape[0]) + self._Q * h
            pass
        powers = [None for _ in range(logn+1)]
        for k in range(logn+1):
            powers[k] = numpy.linalg.matrix_power(IplusQh, 2**k)
            pass
        for k in range(n):
            tmp1 = k+1
            tmp2 = 0
            P = numpy.eye(self.Q.shape[0])
            while tmp1 > 0:
                if tmp1 % 2:
                    P = P @ powers[tmp2]
                tmp1 //= 2
                tmp2 += 1
            self._currentT = ((k+1)/n) * self.T
            self._currentP = P
            obs = numpy.eye(2)
            # extract rows corresponding to count=0
            for i in (1, 2):
                for j in (1, 2):
                    obs[i-1, j-1] = numpy.sum(P[
                        self._arrayidx(i, 0),
                        [self._arrayidx(j, count) for count in range(self.N)]])
            self._observed.append((self._currentT, obs,))
        pass

    def _compute_adaptive(self):
        if self._currentT >= self.T:
            return
        stepsize = self.determine_step_size()
        if 'expQ' in self._opt:
            IplusQh = self.expQ(stepsize)
        else:
            IplusQh = numpy.eye(self._Q.shape[0]) + self._Q * stepsize
            pass
        while self._currentT < self.T:
            # first check if coffin has accumulated too much probability
            if self._currentP[self._arrayidx(1, 0),
                              self._arrayidx(state=3)] >= self.tol/2:
                # it has accumulate too much, so bump up N
                self.N += 1
                # reset stepsize
                stepsize = self.determine_step_size()
                if 'expQ' in self._opt:
                    IplusQh = self.expQ(stepsize)
                else:
                    IplusQh = numpy.eye(self._Q.shape[0]) + self._Q * stepsize
                    pass
            # now check stepsize
            if self._currentT + stepsize > self.T:
                stepsize = self.T - self._currentT
                if 'expQ' in self._opt:
                    IplusQh = self.expQ(stepsize)
                else:
                    IplusQh = numpy.eye(self._Q.shape[0]) + self._Q * stepsize
                    pass
            # step forward time
            self._currentP = self._currentP @ IplusQh
            self._currentT += stepsize
            # extract observed
            obs = numpy.zeros((2, 2))
            for i in (1, 2):
                for j in (1, 2):
                    obs[i-1, j-1] = numpy.sum(self._currentP[
                        self._arrayidx(i, 0),
                        [self._arrayidx(j, count) for count in range(self.N)]])
            self._observed.append((self._currentT, obs,))
        pass

# Now generate, e.g.,
# M = chain(T=100, delta=0.1, tol=1e-6, options='coarse adaptive_N')
# M.compute()
# len(M.observed)

```
````